# Record page number when citing in .tex file for bookkeeping, but hide it in the .pdf

Tags: natbib

I'm using `natbib` to display my citations as simple numbered subscripts. But I also want to record the page number of the source I'm citing in/near the `\citep{}`, just for myself. What's the best way of doing this? Thanks!

Oh, and I don't think I can use `biblatex`!

Comment: %You could just make it a comment.

Comment: While I think the suggestions you've received are reasonable, I'm curious as you why you want to do this in the first place. Why aren't you including the page(s) in the citation? This is normal practice. To put this another way: if the page reference is useful to *you* why are you determined to prevent your reader from enjoying the same convenience?

Comment: Well, it's a balance between providing a sufficient enough citation (for my purposes), and keeping the document clean-looking and uninterrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can create a command, say, `\extendedcitep` with two arguments and throw away one like this

```
\newcommand\extendedcitep[2][]{\citep{#2}}
```

and use it like `\extendedcitep[p.~20]{Aristotle12}`.

Moreover, for your own draft you can redefine the command to put the page number on the margin:

```
\renewcommand\extendedcitep[2][]{\marginpar{\citep{#2}, #1}\citep{#2}}
```

Comment: This will not work if you want to allow `\citep` to work with its usual optional arguments via `\extendedcitep`, though. I guess you'd never want the pages, but you might want the pre-note. Also, `\citep{#2}, #1` will produce something like '(Author YYYY) pp-pp`. Why not use `\citep[#1]{$2}` in the margin? Or does that give errors if `#1` is empty?

Comment: @Boris, I must say those are both great ideas. Thanks. And about the margin citation info, any idea how I could present the page numbers for multiple sources in a nice way? (e.g. `\extendedcitep[p. 200,p. 3]{Aristotle12,Vonnegut1963}`)

Comment: *Update: I just realized this margin info "renewcommand", at least when using subscript citations, doesn't attach the subscript to the previous word, but maintains the space between the last word and the subscript, which doesn't look good. Anyway, the `\extendedcitep` still works great.